# How to reposition keys by Number Order in Java Map?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, collections, android-adapter

I'm trying to remove a particular key from Map and reposition all keys index wise. For example: My map is like **Map<Integer,String>**

```
0,"A"
1,"B"
2,"C"
3,"D"
```

if i remove key 1 then output should be

```
0,"A"
1,"C"
2,"D"
```

How do i keep keys in index wise (0 to size-1) and assign next value to previous key after remove?

*This is required because before insertion in map i need to check whether key exists or not. This scenario required for my **recycler view adapter** to hold unique positions to avoid reloading of items if exists in map*

Comment: Is the expected order dependent on the sorting of the values `A`, `C`, `D` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Values can be any string. Just wanted the keys in sorting order

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, if u want the index to be in that behavior. `Map` is not the answer. use **List** - can use ArrayList[insertion is often] or LinkedList[fast when reading].

Sample:

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();

items.add("A");
items.add("B");
items.add("C");
items.add("D");
```

So if you remove index 1 or B;

```
items.remove(1);
```

The index of C will automatically be 1. Just like you wanted above.

Comment: Correct answer. The index number of any `List` would provide the same purpose if the key in this incorrect use of `Map`. I suggest expanding this Answer to show some example usage.

Answer (score 0):

`Map`s inherently have no order. There is no way to change the keys without taking all the values out of the `Map` and reinserting them with new keys.

It sounds like you may be better off using a `List` instead of a `Map`.

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
// 0 => "A", 1 => "B", 2 => "C"
strings.remove(1);
// 0 => "A", 1 => "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't order the keys on deletion by updating key values. In MAP only way to update keys is removing the key and and re-insert it with new value. That is tricky and expensive. You can go with ArrayList for the desired result as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The `TreeMap<K,V>` in the jdk `java.util` package can meet your needs. Whatever key you delete , the sort will never change.

If you want to define yourself sort method, just use its custom `comparator` to over-write construction method `TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator)` to achieve key sorting.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();  
    map.put(0, "A");
    map.put(1, "B");
    map.put(2, "C");
    map.put(3, "D");
    // whatever key you delete , the sort will not change...
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {  
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I agree with your explanation. But my order is changed. I don't want key 2 after deleting key 1. It should put key 1 with next key's value

Answer (score 0):

you choose a **very bad** way to implement this in adapter
but you can solve it with below code:

```
 final Map<Integer, String> myStupidMap = new HashMap<>();
    myStupidMap.put(1, "A");
    myStupidMap.put(2, "B");
    myStupidMap.put(3, "C");
    myStupidMap.put(4, "D");

    final int[] count = {0};
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        myStupidMap.forEach(new BiConsumer<Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(Integer integer, String s) {
                if (count[0] == 1){
                    myStupidMap.remove(integer);
                }
                count[0]++;
            }
        });
    }
```

i hope useful for you But my suggestion is not to use the map.